# Vector manipulation

Tags: c++, vector

I am not proficient in C++. I have a very short C++ script I am trying to convert to PHP which deals with vectors.

From online documentation I gather that vectors are lists of stuff, somewhat like arrays in PHP but with less features. However, I am struggling to find good documentation on vector manipulation.

For example

```
real32 test(std::vector<T>::iterator First, std::vector<T>::iterator Last)
{
    if(Last - First > 0) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

In this snippet I can hazard a guess at a number of outcomes to do with `Last - First`.

- The difference in the number of elements between each vector
- The difference in the sum of the elements between each vector
- The difference between single elements in each vector (guessing from `iterator` - but this might be the for loop in the `//do stuff part`)

I am trying to RTFM but the [some](https://isocpp.org/) of the on-line [resources](http://www.cplusplus.com/) I have stumbled across don't come across as particularly insightful (although maybe I am not able to ask/search the right question)

What is `Last - First` actually doing in this case?

Comment: Do note that two iterators may belong to two different vectors!

Comment: @Ajay If they do then that function will exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: @Galik, True. But such function is bound to raise runtime error. Try passing different iterators to `vector` and see it handles it well (well, at least in VC++)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function does not take 2 `vector`s, but 2 *`iterators`*, which point at a particular place inside a `vector`. In this case, the first and one-past-the-last elements. This is a normal C++ idiom. (Note that the iterators might actually indicate some sub-part of an existing `vector`, doesn't actually have to be the whole thing).

Therefore the difference is the total number of elements in the `vector`. Usually, one would have a loop handling each element, and incrementing `First` until it hits `Last`.

```
1|2|3|4|5|
^First    ^Last
```

Note that `Last` does not point at `5`, but one past it. `Last` is not a valid element of the `vector`, but a sentinel, indicating when to stop looping.

In this case `Last-First == 5`, since you would have to increment `First` 5 times to hit `Last`.

Reference documentation is not usually the best place to learn the language from. We do have the [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1171191).

Your links:

- [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/): About the standardisation process and committee, not much actual language documentation here.
- [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/): a non-official reference documentation site. In the past, was not very good about fixing errors. So many people prefer:
- [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp): a community-maintained wiki of reference documentation.

There is no "official" reference documentation other than The Standard, a draft of which can be found on isocpp.org, but really, don't try to read that, it is experts-only, aimed at compiler implementers. I'm not even going to link to it.

To be honest, I struggle to find a really good beginners tutorial online.

Comment: Strictly speaking we don't know that these two iterators point to the first and last elements of the vector, only that they point to a beginning and end portion of the vector. Their difference is the number of elements that lie between those two points.